# Script not running at startup using crontab

Tags: usb, scripts, 18.04, cron, startup

I have been trying to launch a script of mine at start-up using both rc.local and crontab methods but neither are working

Here is my script contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo hue spectrum 2
exit 0
```

Here is my crontab contents (minus the comments):

```
@reboot /home/ben/Documents/startup_scripts/hue+.sh
```

EDIT:
I tried using the echo command to simulate me typing in my pass word in one line but alas, that did not work either.
Here is that version of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo <mypassword> | sudo -S hue spectrum 2
exit 0
```

EDIT 2:
I do use the sudo crontab file and the hue command starts an open source version of NZXT's CAM software that lets me control NZXT devices in my computer (cooler, fans, LEDs, etc) also here is the "hue.log" file for those who have asked for it

```
/home/ben/Documents/startup_scripts/hue+.sh: line 2: hue: command not found
```

I don't know hwy it says command not found this command 100% works with sudo

EDIT 3:
I added myself to the group "dialout" and now the command works without sudo, unfortunately the log file is identical to what it was before and the script still does not work on startup

```
/home/ben/Documents/startup_scripts/hue+.sh: line 2: hue: command not found
```

Comment: the script works if I run it normally so I don't think that can be the problem but I'm honestly stumped at this point, even taking the command from the script and placing it in rc.local does not work

Comment: Who or what at system startup inputs password which `sudo` requires? :-)

Comment: You're right no one :/, but I tried running it without sudo and the script will not work. Is there a way to simulate me inputting in my password after log in or at startup? That's what I do in windows to run programs that require administrator permission.

Comment: Where is `hue` located (`which hue`) and what does it do (in particular, does it interact with the graphical display)?

Comment: Replace the line in the script `sudo hue spectrum 2` with `hue spectrum 2 &>>/home/ben/Documents/startup_scripts/hue.log`. Reboot your computer and post content of the file `/home/ben/Documents/startup_scripts/hue.log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution may be very situational to me, but i added a sleep command to my crontab file to give the computer more time, and it miraculously worked no reason it shouldn't have worked without the sleep command but it seems to have foxed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Add the script to `root`'s crontab.

`sudo crontab -e`

You can now leave out the `sudo` in the script.

Comment: Unfortunately I have already done that and no dice :/